converting keras model to tensorflow lite to use in Kivy app
I am trying to convert the keras model to tensorflow lite, and use it in the android app development using kivy
model -
model_v3 = tf.keras.applications.MobileNet(
  weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
  )

for layer in model_v3.layers[:]:
    layer.trainable = True

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

for layer in model_v3.layers:
  model.add(layer)

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

converting code as per the doc
model.save('model.keras')
model = keras.models.load_model('/content/model.keras')

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('mobilenet_224.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)

I used this model in the kivy app, the build is successfull, and the app is installed on the android, but when the app is started to run, i got this error

11-12 10:12:50.932  6678 10552 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 269, in jnius.jnius.JavaClass.init


11-12 10:12:50.933  6678 10552 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 383, in jnius.jnius.JavaClass.call_constructor


11-12 10:12:50.933  6678 10552 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 79, in jnius.jnius.check_exception


11-12 10:12:50.934  6678 10552 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Contents of /mobilenet_224.tflite does not encode a valid TensorFlow Lite
model: Could not open '/mobilenet_224.tflite'.


11-12 10:12:50.934  6678 10552 I python  :  The model allocation is null/empty java.lang.IllegalArgumentException


11-12 10:12:50.934  6678 10552 I python  : Python for android ended.

I used this repo as reference for creating the kivy app - https://github.com/macrodrigues/butterfly_detector/blob/master/app/model.py
i used the dependencies in buildozer.spec
android.gradle_dependencies = org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+,org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:+,org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+
could you please help me on solving this error and why this error occuring, thanks

I got this issue solved from the help of Bob who is a member of kivy discord group, the solution is the tflite model should not be in the root folder instead it should be in a sub-folder
In Kivy path, Instead of the model path like model.tflite, save the model in a sub-folder liek models/model.tflite then it will work
The issue is not in path mentioned in the kivy program while loading the model
